# how to verify the devices connected to system using opentok

Tags: opentok

I am using opentok 2.0. I want to check if camera and microphone are connected to the system using opentok 2.0. How can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your camera and microphone is connected to the system, you should be able to see and hear yourself

Comment: Was this supposed to be a answer or a critic.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to a session as a publisher and check for `stream.hasVideo`...

Example:

```
session.connect(userToken, function () {
    var publisherProperties = {insertMode: "append", width: $('#publisher-tokbox').width(), height: $('#publisher-tokbox').height()};

    var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher-tokbox', publisherProperties, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Publisher initialized.");
        }
    });
    publisher.on("streamCreated", function (event) {
        console.log("The publisher started streaming.", event);
        if (event.stream.hasVideo) {
            console.log("Video is present");
        }

    });

    self.set('publisher', publisher);
    session.publish(publisher);
});
```

Note that the user needs to grant access to the camera in his browser settings.